# Can I customize failure messages in Biometric prompt?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I am implementing BiometricPrompt in my app, everything is fine except that I am not able to change some failure messages. BiometricPrompt class provide methods to change the title, subtitle, description and negative button. Check code below:

```
    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.verifiy_your_identity))
                .setSubtitle(mContext.getString(R.string.place_your_finger))
   .setDescription(mContext.getString(R.string.to_verify_your_identity))
                .setNegativeButtonText(mContext.getString(R.string.cancel))
                .build();
```

if the fingerprint is wrong I am getting a message saying: No match. 
if I remove my finger fast, I get:  Keep your finger on the sensor a little bit longer

how can I change these messages?

[image: Image Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot customize default errors provided by `BiometricPrompt`. If you want to show your own customised errors, better option would be to look for ***error codes*** provided by `BiometricPrompt`. Then you can use `switch` cases or `if-else` and based on ***error code*** you can show your custom error message.